# autostart not working in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, autostart

I've added link to EventGhost in c:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
but eventGhost isn't launched with windows - why?

EventGhost has special complatibility rights to always run as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a scheduled task and locally run it as administrator so that the payload is started with locally elevated user rights. Then you can choose how to run the task, for example after Windows boot or after a user authentification.